# upgrade to DSE 4.6 endpoint_snitch issue

Tags: datastax-enterprise

I am testing upgrading to 4.6, and there seems to be a change in the snitch. 4.5 ran fine with.

```
endpoint_snitch: com.datastax.bdp.snitch.DseDelegateSnitch
```

Configured in the cassandra.yaml file, but 4.6 fails to start.  The only way I can get it to start is to use one of the classic snitches, but then I have to configure my Datacenter names and such... How do I use the DseDelegateSnitch.

I am getting the following error with the above config when I use the DseDelegateSnitch.

```
Fatal configuration error
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: DseDelegateSnitch is now handled automatically; please set endpoint_snitch in cassandra.yaml to any valid IEndpointSnitch (probably whatever is configured for delegated_snitch in dse.yaml).  Also remove delegated_snitch from dse.yaml if it is still set there.
        at com.datastax.bdp.config.DseConfigurationLoader.loadConfig(DseConfigurationLoader.java:47)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.loadConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:136)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.<clinit>(DatabaseDescriptor.java:112)
```

The node will start when I use a snitch such as propertyfilesnitch.

Thanks in advance.

**Update on solution**

I did not have the delegate snitch in the dse.yaml file, but I did have DseDelegateSnitch in cassandra.yaml.  I ran this:

```
sed -r 's/DseDelegateSnitch/DseSimpleSnitch/g' /etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
```

And I am back in business.

Thanks to the Datastax's Docs team!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The updgrade instructions for the snitch are here: http://datastax.com/documentation/upgrade/doc/upgrade/datastax_enterprise/upgradeTo4_6.html

Starting in DataStax Enterprise 4.6, the endpoint snitch is set in cassandra.yaml, not dse.yaml. Add the emove the delegated_snitch setting from dse.yaml and

Procedure

Follow the steps in General upgrade procedure until you start the node.

- Open cassandra.yaml in a text editor.
- Add a endpoint_snitch option set to the snitch you set in
  delegated_snitch in dse.yaml.

  DataStax Enterprise 4.6 now automatically handles delegated snitches. If the old delegated_snitch in dse.yaml is set to com.datastax.bdp.snitch.DseDelegateSnitch, set the endpoint_snitch in cassandra.yaml to com.datastax.bdp.snitch.DseSimpleSnitch.

`endpoint_snitch: com.datastax.bdp.snitch.DseSimpleSnitch`

- Open dse.yaml in a text editor and remove the delegated_snitch
  option.
- Repeat these steps for each node in the cluser.

Comment: I did not have the delegated_snitch in the dse file, but I did have com.datastax.bdp.snitch.DseDelegateSnitch in the cass yaml file.  I updated to the com.datastax.bdp.snitch.DseSimpleSnitch and it starts :)

Answer (score 3):

As the error says, you need to move the delegated_snitch setting out of dse.yaml and set that in the cassandra.yaml.

When upgrading you really want to start from the new versions default dse.yaml and cassandra.yaml files and merge in any changes you made.  The default settings and configs will usually change between major versions.

Comment: Where can I get the yaml files?

Comment: They are in the resources/dse/conf/ and resources/cassandra/conf directories

Comment: This error message is actually misleading.  I did not have a delegated_snitch in the dse.yaml, but I did have the snitch set to the old com.datastax.bdp.snitch.DseDelegateSnitch.